# Missing JUNIT Jar Exception while building project using Maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am in the beginning phase of Maven. I created a project and was trying to use the command. what is missing at my end? I am trying to compile and run a TestSuite File:

```
mvn clean package
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.myProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myTest</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>egdsvTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

but i get the below exception after using it.

**Exception**

```
 D:\MVN_Shirish_Project\Test>mvn clean package
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]
    [INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethrea
    ded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
    [INFO]
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building Test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Test ---
    [INFO] Deleting D:\MVN_Shirish_Project\Test\target
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Test
    ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
    i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\MVN_Shirish_Project\Test\src\
    main\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Test ---

    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. b
    uild is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\MVN_Shirish_Project\Test\target\classe
    s
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ eg
    dsvTest ---
    [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources,
    i.e. build is platform dependent!
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\MVN_Shirish_Project\Test\src\
    test\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 
    Test ---
    [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. b
    uild is platform dependent!
    [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\MVN_Shirish_Project\Test\target\test-c
    lasses
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Test ---
    [INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\MVN_Shirish_Project\Test\target\surefi
    re-reports
    [WARNING] Missing POM for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit3:jar:2.12.4
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 0.968 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2014-10-14T12:28:09+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/247M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.
    12.4:test (default-test) on project Test: Unable to generate classpath: org
    .apache.maven.artifact.resolver.MultipleArtifactsNotFoundException: Missing:
    [ERROR] ----------
    [ERROR] 1) org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit3:jar:2.12.4
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
    [ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.surefire -DartifactI
    d=surefire-junit3 -Dversion=2.12.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file t
    here:
    [ERROR] mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.surefire -DartifactId=
    surefire-junit3 -Dversion=2.12.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url
    ] -DrepositoryId=[id]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] Path to dependency:
    [ERROR] 1) dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
    [ERROR] 2) org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-junit3:jar:2.12.4
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] ----------
    [ERROR] 1 required artifact is missing.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] for artifact:
    [ERROR] dummy:dummy:jar:1.0
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] from the specified remote repositories:
    [ERROR] m1 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
    ch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR]
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
    d the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
    xception
```

Comment: `3.8.1` is a very old JUnit version. Unless you specifically need to use this, try updating it to the latest (replace `3.8.1` with `4.11`). It may solve your problem, since the chosen Surefire plugin is going to be affected by this change.

Comment: @Duncan : I downloaded the latest jar for JUNIT (4.8.1) from maven repository but in which location i should palce this jar now for the pom.xml to identify it?

Comment: With Maven, you don't typically download anything yourself. Instead, if you update your POM file as I described in my first comment, it should all happen auto-magically when you run `mvn package`.

Comment: This is the error i got 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Test: Could not resolve dependenc
ies for project com.egdsv.myProject:Test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access m1
 (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.mav
en.surefire:surefire-junit4:jar:2.12.4 has not been downloaded from it before. -
> [Help 1]
I checked for the jar in the repostiroy and i found it but dunno y this error is coming.

Comment: Moreover i also tried changing offline mode false to true in the .settings file but no success.:(

Comment: It sounds like you're not connected to the Internet? Maven needs to be able to contact online repositories to find artifacts. This seems to be a networking issue of some description.

Answer (score 1):

Maven works by creating a local repository in your desktop or the machine you have installed maven and running this goal.

In the process of maven running the goal, it first tries to get all the dependent jar files from Central repository as you have listed in your comments M1 or M2 and then stores them under C:/Users/yourname/.m2/repository folder (assuming you are using a windows machine) or the corresponding user folder in other OS systems.

Then it uses the jars to run the build as required per the goals given.

Now in your case, you got to figure out a way to connect to the repositories (check your settings.xml located in the .m2 folder in your User directory) and check if you can connect to the internet central maven repositories. If not you can get the jar file and manually install them as advised in the error you have got. Once you do that I think you should get past this issue. Let me know if you still have the issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was caused by me doing an offline build (i.e. `mvn -o install`) and me not having that jar installed in my local Maven repository yet. Doing an online build (`mvn install`) fixed it.